# When you run "rails server" how do you get the ruby version to match what you see with "ruby -v"?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

I can't seem to get my version of ruby when running "rails server" to be the same as the one in terminal.  If I run commands like `ruby -v` I get 1.9.3 which is the version that I want to use.  But I get 1.8.7 when I use `rails server`.  Any idea how I get get my local server to leverage 1.9.3?  I am using a Mac with Lion.

---

```
CHRISs-MacBook-Pro:test_app chrisrothstein$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p125 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

CHRISs-MacBook-Pro:test_app chrisrothstein$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16 revision 34643) [x86_64-darwin11.3.0]

CHRISs-MacBook-Pro:test_app chrisrothstein$ rails server
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.2.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2012-04-07 15:48:50] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2012-04-07 15:48:50] INFO  ruby 1.8.7 (2010-01-10) [universal-darwin11.0]
[2012-04-07 15:48:50] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=53174 port=3000
```

Comment: This may help you: http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=47491

Comment: What does `gem list rails` show? If you don't have rails installed in the gemset of the rvm Ruby you're using, then the `rails` command could be finding the system Ruby gem which get installed to `/usr/bin` so will be on your path. A simple `gem install rails` could be all that's needed to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

If this is a Rails 3 app, then you're using bundler by default. So, run your server within the bundler context.

Do `bundle install` if you haven't already to install all the gems in your `Gemfile`. The run your server this way instead:

```
bundle exec rails s
```

This should make the ruby version match what is shown in rvm.